# Implementing a Gaussian elimination solver for Simon's algorithm's outcome of linear equations

Tags: programming, quantum-algorithms, simons-algorithm

I'm trying to implement a gaussian elimination solver for the linear equations that are the outcome from simon's algorithm. I implemented two solutions,

- first: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45527097
- second: https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/52270

They both work fine for systems which can be reduced to rref (reduced row echelon form), where every non-zero coefficient in a row is the only non-zero.

But neither can handle simple cases like:
Given secret b = 11. Measurements in simon's algorithm: 00 and 11.

The augmented given matrix I put as a param for a solver would be:
|| 1 1 | 0 ||
|| 0 0 | 0 ||
or just (reducing to non trivial equations):
|| 1 1 | 0 ||
I would expect the non trivial solution would be: b0 = 1 and b1 = 1.

Does someone has an idea or an implementation how to handle this cases?
I'm a bit confused because what we are solving here is a special version of a homogeneous system
Ax = 0
If A is non-singular, than it only has one (the trivial zero) solution.
Otherwise it has an infinite number of non-trivial solutions and gaussian elimination doesn't work here.
See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Homogeneous_systems

But the example I posted above has exactly two solutions (00 and 11). I can only attribute this to the fact that we have a special case here with modulo 2, right?

However, all articles and books I looked into don't show an implementation of how to solve this. And from my inner feeling there are two options left:

- I'm thinking to complicated
- Or it's not solvable with the suggested gaussian-elimination.

The latter is underlined by the fact that Google's Cirq uses svd (Singular Value Decomposition) that I don't understand yet.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the $00$ measurement is actually unusable: any string $s$ is orthogonal to $00$, so this doesn't give you a bit of informration on $s$.

Furthermore, as noted in [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/2224/10454), for a secret of $n$ bits, only $n-1$ equations are to be used. Otherwise, the only solution is $s=0$ if the equations are linearly independent.

In your case, the equations are not linearly independent (because of the $00$ measurement), since $11\oplus11=00$, which explains why the true solution $11$ is still possible. Note also that the zero vector will always be a solution of the system, since it will always be orthogonal to all the measurements you've got.

Thus, after solving for $s\neq0$ using $n-1$ equations, you ought to verify the hypothesis that $s\neq0$. This is quite easy: query for $f(x)$ and $f(x\oplus s)$. If they are equal, then $s$ is necessarily different from $0$. Otherwise, it means that $s=0$.

That said, I happen to have coded an implementation in Python some time ago. Note that it is not guarantee to be the fastest possible methods, but it should work.

```python
import numpy as np

class NotFullRankError(Exception):
    pass

def solve(bitstrings: list[str]) -> str:
    matrix = np.vstack([np.array([int(x) for x in s], dtype=bool) for s in bitstrings])
    
    # Check if there are n - 1 equations and whether the nil vector is among them
    if not matrix.any(axis=1).all() or matrix.shape[0] != matrix.shape[1] - 1:
        raise NotFullRankError()
    
    # Reduce
    for i in range(matrix.shape[0] - 1):
        mask = matrix[i:, i]
        matrix[i:] = np.vstack((matrix[i:][mask], matrix[i:][~mask]))
        matrix[i + 1:i + mask.sum()] ^= matrix[i]
        
        # Check if the equations were linearly independent
        if not matrix.any(axis=1).all():
            raise NotFullRankError()
        
    # Transforming matrix from a ref to a rref
    for i in range(1, matrix.shape[0]):
        index = np.where(matrix[i])[0][0]
        mask = matrix[:i, index]
        matrix[:i][mask] ^= matrix[i]
    
    index = np.where(~np.diag(matrix))[0]
            
    if index.shape[0]:
        index = index[0]
    else:
        index = matrix.shape[1] - 1

    return "".join(str(x) for x in np.hstack((matrix[:index, index], [1], matrix[index:, index])))
```

A quick explanation concerning the following lines:

```python
    index = np.where(~np.diag(matrix))[0]
            
    if index.shape[0]:
        index = index[0]
    else:
        index = matrix.shape[1] - 1

    return np.hstack((matrix[:index, index], [1], matrix[index:, index]))
```

Once the matrix is rref, two cases are possible:

- the diagonal is full of $1$s, like:
  $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0&1\\0&1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1&1\end{pmatrix}$$
- the diagonal "misses" a step, like:
  $$B=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

`index` will represent the index at which the diagonal misses a step, which is $n-1$ for the first case and the first zero on the diagonal for the second one.

Let us consider the second case for now. Note that the last row will always be $\begin{pmatrix}0&\cdots&0&1\end{pmatrix}$, which implies that the last bit of $s$ must be $0$. Indeed, we must have $Bs=\begin{pmatrix}0\\\vdots\\0\end{pmatrix}$, so the last line of the system translates to $1\cdot s_n=0$. Essentially, this means that you can remove the last row of the matrix, since each of these elements will me multiplied by the last bit of $s$, which is $0$. You can then perform the same reasoning, until you're left with a matrix of the first case. Thus, if we show that in the first case, the solution $s$ is given by the last column to which one appends $1$, this would explain the method (since `matrix[index:, index]` is a vector full of zeroes).

Now for the first case, since the matrix is rref it means that every row on the matrix contain at most exactly two $1$s: one on the diagonal and one on the last column. Thus, when writing down $As=\begin{pmatrix}0\\\vdots\\0\end{pmatrix}$, all of the equations can be written as $s_i\oplus A_{i,n}\cdot s_n=0$, which implies that $s_i=A_{i,n}\cdot s_n$. If $s_n=0$, then this will yield the zero vector, which we don't want. Thus, we impose $s_n=1$, which then yield $s_i=A_{i,n}$.

All in all, once the index at which the diagonal misses a step is found, we simply have to take the column corresponding to this index up to that row, add a $1$ and complete with $0$ to find $s$, which explains the code.

Now, if you want to use this code, here's how you can do it. If you measured $10010$, $11010$, $10110$ and $10001$, you can find the unique non-zero $s$ which is orthogonl to all of these like this:

```python
res = solve(["10010", "11010", "10110", "10001"]) # Compute s
print(res)
```

Running it with the list containing only `"11"` returns `"11"` as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It will take some time until I understand it. I'll comment later on.

Comment: Ok I translated your code to my PL of choice (TypeScript). 
I noticed that the line "index = np.where(matrix[i])[0][0]" is unnecessary in # Reduce.

Comment: Furthermore I want to know if it is really necessary that "# Check if the equations were linearly independent each" is inside the # Reduce-Loop.

Comment: I recognized that your code using JupyterLab dependent on the measurement sometimes runs into a NotFullRankError and sometimes it solves it. Example: 
Given secret 0101 and measurements 0111, 1111, 1000. -> Error. 
Given same secret 0101 and measurements 0111, 0101, 1000 -> Solves it.
Is this an expected behavior? How to handle? Just rerun?

Comment: @Oli Indeed, this line is useless, nice catch! The check could be done outside the loop, but doing it at each iteration may save a lot of computations, which is why it is inside the loop. Finally, concerning your example, rerunning it would have no effect: the code is deterministic. The problem is that your measurements are not linearly independent, since $0111\oplus 1111=1000$. As a proof, note that the secret $0011$ would also work with these measurements.

Comment: With "rerun" I have meant also to carry out the measurements again. But it is generally a scenario that can not be prevented or unless you check whether all measurements are linearly independent, which in my opinion is too costly, right?

Comment: @Oli You're right about this then. If your measurements are not linearly independent, the simplest method is simply to redo the measurements. It may of course be possible to do better by keeping some of them, but it is actually proven that getting $n-1$ linearly independent equations happens with probability at least $\frac14$, which is independent from $n$. Thus, it is not too costly to simply redo the algorithm entirely.

Comment: Thank you for helping me!